# Google Maps with Lightbox on Image effect

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox

So I have a custom google map that I put points on and an HTML popup window shows when you click on that image.

The problem I'm having is that I want to use a lightbox/fancybox effect on images inside the popup HTML box. It seems like since these are dynamically generated that jquery is not recognizing them on page load or can't find them.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function initialize() {

        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(39.470125,83.605957 ), 4); // Taklamakan desert
            map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
            map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
            var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);

            blueIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";

            // Set up our GMarkerOptions object

            markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };


            // Creates a marker at the given point
            // Clicking the marker will hide it
            function createMarker(latlng, number, myHtml)
            {
                var marker = new GMarker(latlng, markerOptions);
                marker.value = number;
                GEvent.addListener(marker,"click", function() {
                    map.openInfoWindowHtml(latlng, myHtml);
                });
                return marker;
            }



            var latlng = new GLatLng(40.641468, 87.756958 );
            var myHtml = 'Yingpan Man was excavated here near the Könchi River. Yingpan was active from 300 BCE–500 CE. <img src="http://www.penn.museum/silkroad/images/objects/thumbs/yingpan_man_web_thumb.jpg" alt="Yingpan Man" /> <br /><br /><br />';
            map.addOverlay(createMarker(latlng, 0, myHtml));

            var latlng1 = new GLatLng(39.548953, 88.899536 );
            var myHtml1 = 'The Beauty of Xiahoe<br /> <a class="fancier_image" href="images/objects/beauty_xiaohe.jpg"> <img src="images/objects/thumbs/beauty_xiaohe_thumb.jpg" alt="The Beauty of Xiahoe" /> </a> <br /><br /><br />';
            map.addOverlay(createMarker(latlng1, 1, myHtml1));


}
 }


$(document).ready(function() {


    $(".fancier_image").fancybox({
    'overlayShow'   : false,
    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    'easingIn'      : 'easeOutBack',
    'easingOut'     : 'easeInBack'

    });

});

</script>
```

I have confirmed that the Fancybox actually works on the page with a static image that is not in the Google map.

I have remedied this type of situation before by finding the thing with jquery

```
$(document).find('a.fancier_image')
```

but I need a jquery event to go off of and since the image was dynamically created after page load I can't assign anything in the HTML portion of the popup a .click event (or at least I don't know how).

So to recap I just want to be able to put a lightbox/fancybox on an image inside a google maps popup HTML off of a clicked GLatLng point.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Might not fully understand how your code is behaving, but before returning marker at the end of createMarker(), have you tried adding this:

```
$(document).find('a.fancier_image').fancybox({
    'overlayShow'   : false,
    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    'easingIn'      : 'easeOutBack',
    'easingOut'     : 'easeInBack'

    });
```

Edit:
How about using the [.livequery() plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) for this?

`$("a.fancier_image").livequery(addFancyBox);`

Comment: I tried that. Basically, because the image is made dynamically by Google Maps I do not have an event to go off of to use $(document).find('a.fancier_image').

Comment: Updated original answer with a different idea.